# How to get from Postgres database to Hadoop Sequence File?

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, accumulo

I need to get data from a Postgres database to an Accumulo database. We're hoping to using sequence files to run map/reduce job to do this, but aren't sure how to start. For internal technical reasons, we need to avoid Sqoop.

Will this be possible without Sqoop? Again, I'm really not sure where to start. Do I write a java class to read all records (millions) into JDBC and somehow output that to an HDFS sequence file?

Thanks for any input!

P.S. - 
I should have mentioned that using a delimited file is the problem we're having now. Some of our are long character fields that contain the delimiter, and therefore don't parse correctly. The field may even have a tab in it. We wanted to go from Postgres straight to HDFS without parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export data from your database as a CSV or tab-delimited, or pipe-delimited, or Ctrl-A (Unicode 0x0001) - delimited files. Then you can copy those files into HDFS and run a very simple MapReduce job, maybe even consisting just of a Mapper and configured to read the file format you used and to output the sequence files.

This would allow to distribute the load for the creating of the sequence files between the servers of the Hadoop cluster.

Also, most likely, this will not be a one-time deal. You will have to load the data from the Postgres database into HDFS on the regular basis. They you would be able to tweak your MapReduce job to merge the new data in.

Comment: I should have mentioned that using a delimited file is the problem we're having now. Some of our are long character fields that contain the delimiter, and therefore don't parse correctly. The field may even have a tab in it. We wanted to go from Postgres straight to HDFS without parsing.

Comment: @user1660256: It seems like you are just kicking the can down the road. How are you planning to process the data when it is loaded into the HDFS? You would have to parse it at some point.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. Once it's in a sequence file, the data would be in key/value pairs, and we would load the value as is without any parsing, not caring if the delimiters were in the value or not.

Comment: p.s. - How do you tell Postgres to export with the Ctrl-A delimiter? I don't see that option. That might work for us.

Comment: In psql: \copy table_name to '/path/to/file' delimiter  E'\x01'

Comment: @user1660256: When you mentioned moving data from Postgres to HDFS and using sequence files, I jumped to a conclusion that you planned to be able to query that data with Hive. By default, Hive reads sequence files, ignores the key and treats the value as a table row with fields separated by 0x0001.

Comment: Your assumption that sequence files -> Accumulo is easy is not right.  Accumulo uses something called tfiles and it's a bit more complicated than just keys and values.

Comment: Even if the column delimiter is `\x01` / Ctrl-A, if the values contain `\n` it will still break, because PostgreSQL `COPY` is hardcoded to always use `\n` for line delimiter otherwise it will quote the value and Hive doesn't support quoted values.

Answer (score 1):

You can serialize your data using [Avro](https://avro.apache.org/), although it won't be very fast (especially when using python like in the example) and then load it into the hdfs.

Assuming you have database foo:

```
postgres=# \c foo
You are now connected to database "foo" as user "user".
foo=# 

foo=# \d bar
                              Table "public.bar"
Column |          Type           |                     Modifiers                     
--------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------------
key    | integer                 | not null default nextval('bar_key_seq'::regclass)
value  | character varying(1024) | not null
```

You can create avro schema like below:

```
{"namespace": "foo.avro",
 "type": "record",
 "name": "bar",
 "fields": [
     {"name": "id", "type": "int"},
     {"name": "value", "type": "string"}
 ]
}
```

And then serialize your data row by row:

```
import psycopg2
import avro.schema
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader, DataFileWriter
from avro.io import DatumReader, DatumWriter

schema = avro.schema.parse(open("foo.avsc").read())
writer = DataFileWriter(open("foo.avro", "w"), DatumWriter(), schema)

c = psycopg2.connect(user='user', password='s3cr3t', database='foo')
cur = c.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM bar')

for row in cur.fetchall():
    writer.append({"id": row[0], "value": row[1]})

writer.close()
cur.close()
c.close()
```

Alternatively you can use serialize your data using plain json.

Comment: This is what I'd like to do but I hope there's already a tool to do this, both for exporting from PostgreSQL to Avro and importing Avro files to PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

There is http://sqoop.apache.org/ which should do what you ask.